IP address in network (MacBook setting) is different than the IP in the router's config page
I would like to bind the IP address with my MacBook’s MAC address (static IP) but strangely I found:

The IP address 192.168.1.7 in network:

Is different with the IP 192.168.0.113 in the router's config page:


I couldn't access my router through 192.168.0.1, while my phone can. The router's config page above is a screenshot from my iPhone.



Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Your MacBook and your phone are not connected to the same network.

You probably have two devices acting as NAT gateways and DHCP servers on your network. The second (downstream) device doing NAT splits your network into two subnets. Reconfigure that downstream device to just be a bridging AP instead of a NAT gateway.

The issue is that your Macbook is on a different subnet and assigned to the wrong gateway (192.168.1.1). The current network "subnet mask" appears to be 255.255.255.0 and your router's IP is on a different subnet.
The MacBook is on 192.168.1.x and the router is on 192.168.0.x. You either have to change the subnet mask on both devices to 255.255.0.0 so they can see each other OR just change the IP address of the MacBook so that it is on the same subnet (192.168.0.x) and the gateway address is 192.168.0.1 (router's address).
As far as a static address, manually set the IP, subnet mask, and gateway in the network properties for the device instead of accepting automatic (DHCP) settings.  You should make sure the statically assigned IP doesn't fall into the DHCP range defined in the router and would also want to add the static address to your router's list of assigned addresses.
Your mesh router configuration issues are another matter.

This answer assumes that both devices are on the same network segment. This is very unlikely.
